# Como puedo enlazar mi archivo php a html?

Tags: php

Me dijeron que se usa el tag "require" busque en internet y hay varios haciendo la misma pregunta desde hace años.

El código es:

```php
<?php 
  $cal = $_REQUEST["cal"]; 
  $lad = $_REQUEST["lad"]; 
  switch($cal) { 
      case "area": $area = $lad * $lad; 
      echo "El area del cuadrado es $area"; 
      break; 
      case "peri": $peri = $lad * 4; 
      echo "El perimetro es $peri"; 
      break; 
      default: echo "Debe seleccionar una opción"; 
      break; 
      require 1.html;
<?
```

Comment: Hola, agrega mas información y el código asociado a la pregunta por favor.

Comment: Si colocas a detalle lo que tratas de hacer y el código involucrado, te podremos ayudar, aunque esa pregunta seguro ya tiene respuesta

Comment: <?php
    $cal = $_REQUEST["cal"];  
    $lad = $_REQUEST["lad"];   
switch($cal) {  
 case "area":  
$area = $lad * $lad;  
echo "El area del cuadrado es $area";    
break;  
  
case "peri":  
$peri = $lad * 4;  
echo "El perimetro es $peri";  
break;  
  
default:  
echo "Debe seleccionar una opción";  
         
 break;  
require 1.html; <--- Este es la etiqueta que encontre pero al ejecutar la pagina me muestra el error en la linea de require del documento php :'( Si soy principiante en esto.
?>

Comment: Hola que tal Henry, recuerda que PHP es lenguaje del lado del servidor, si tenes tus archivos guardados con extension HTML no vas a leer etiquetas php. Si podes guardar tus archivos PHP e incluir tu codigo HTML y dentro del HTML podes importar tu otros archivos PHP con require o con include de PHP.

Comment: Los REQUEST de donde los traes? como pasas los datos por el REQUEST, no es recomendable usar REQUEST porque lo que hace es traer todos los tipo de metodos. Te conviene usar siempre el metodo que vas a usar ejemplo GET, POST, PUT.

Comment: si cambias el require por include("1.html");  deberia funcionar. Ojo que tenes al reves el cierre de PHP

Comment: Para que el `require` funcione debe estar antes del `break`, no después. El código sale del `switch` cuando encuentra `break`, ignorando lo que haya después. Si sigue sin funcionar mejora tu pregunta, indicando si da algún error o cuál es el comportamiento.

Comment: aparte de lo comentado anteriormente, no tienes cerrado el switch (lo abres con la llave, pero no lo cierras). Probablemente el require deba estar antes del break, o si es depues del break, entonces tendras que cerrar el if antes del require...